# Unicode nepali fonts looking different in different devices

Tags: unicode, fonts, raspberry-pi, raspbian, kiosk-mode

As in the attached Image, I have been developing kiosk system for district development committee Chitwan with use of Raspberry pi, and chromium browser in kiosk mode with local hosted webpage.

I got a problem in unicode Nepali fonts as in image. Fonts are looking as usual in Windows but looks ugly and messing in Linux and Raspbian distribution.

Do you have any idea about this? If so Please help me to sort out the problem.[image]

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

Linux and Windows (and OSX, and Android) have different text rendering engines.

It is very hard to display text on-screen cleanly, typical pixels are too big to draw small shapes such as text glyphs without distortions of all kinds. Which is why serif fonts are rarely used on computer systems, serifs are even smaller shapes so they are more affected by those distortions.

Different systems apply different distortion rules, that is why text does not look the same on different systems. Very often there is no "good" choice, you improve one parameter at the expense of another.

Users react negatively to rules they are not used to (Linux people hate Windows rendering, Windows people hate Apple rendering and so on). It's just a matter of habit, force them to use the new rendering for some months, they will hate returning to the previous one.

So most probably, you don't like it because you're not used to it.

Next option, the designer of the Nepali fonts only tested them in Windows, spent a lot of time tuning for windows and workaround-ing Windows rendering bugs. The result in Linux is unsatisfactory because those bugs are not present in Linux, the workarounds trigger other problems, and Linux has other bugs the fonts are not tuned for. However this is very unlikely, Linux has a very mature text rendering stack those days, and the windows versions that required drastic workarounds in fonts are quite old nowadays (you still find such problems early TTF fonts for windows).

So most probably just the first case. There are lots of tips on the Internet to tune Linux to use the same rendering as windows (infinality, etc). It's not a good idea unless you only target windows users and windows fonts.